# package javafx.media does not exist

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to programming and don't know what to do... jGRASP gives this error (the title) when i try to run an mp3 file using java via this code :

```
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;

public class hehe{

  public static void main(String[]args){

    String krow="hoho.mp3";
    Media trial = new Media(krow);
    MediaPlayer Ply = new MediaPlayer(trial);
    Ply.play();

  }

}
```

I searched for a solution but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download `e(fx)clipse plugin` or use `NetBeans` or `IntelliJ`. If you are using 'regular' Eclipse, you need to add `jfxrt.jar` to your classpath.

What you are using is `JavaFX`. It comes along with your JDK. However, `jfxrt.jar` is not on standard classpath.

In spite of resolving that, your program won't run because running `JavaFX` program is different from running 'usual' Java programs.  You need to extend the `Application` class and create a scene graph.

[Have a look here on how to get started.](http://codelatte.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/getting-started-with-javafx-hello-world-2/)